# How can I split the signal in half?

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of signals loaded into a .mat file as double. As seen in the graph, there is a noise signal in the environment until the 53rd second. After 53 seconds there is noise + signal. I want to separate noise and noise + signal in matlab. How can I write a code for this? I can see it directly as the 53rd second in this graph, but since I have many different signals, I want to automatically get only the noise part of each signal, so the window length in the array.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `find()` function can be used to retrieve the index that corresponds to the 53rd second and split the signal into two arrays at that point. Just in case the sample point does not land on exactly 53s it is good to find the smallest value of `t` that is greater or equal to 53.

```
%Test signal and time, t vector (replace with your vectors)%
t = (0: 0.5: 180);
Test_Signal = rand(1,length(t));

Index = find(t >= 53,1);

%Seperating the two regions of the test signal%
Noise = Test_Signal(1:Index);
Signal_Plus_Noise = Test_Signal(Index+1:end);
```

Comment: thank you for your comment. Thank you for your comment. If you don't mind, can we contact me by e-mail? edadaneda@gmail.com

Comment: I'd prefer to keep things on Stack Overflow. What are your concerns with the code?

Comment: I have 600 different signals. All of them have different noise detection times. I can manually see it as the 53rd second for this signal, but can I write the separation code between noise and noise + signal automatically for 600 signals?

Comment: Some of the sequence of the graph I threw in the question is as follows;
number of windows: ... 219 |    220   | 221 | ...
values:                     0.4497 | 0.4497 | 0.4545
here after the 220th window it starts to detect the signal. but I am looking for how to detect automatically for each signal.

Comment: Maybe by smoothing out the signal and then using the derivative to detect the change when the signal starts to slope. Maybe you could add a sample data set/signal to you question.